# How many triples $(x,y,n)$ are there such that $x^n - y^n = 2^{100}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> How many triples $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N^+}^2$ and $n \gt 1$ are there such that $x^n - y^n = 2^{100}$

I dont know how to start. Any hint will be helpful.

I know the identity $x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \cdots + xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$.
I think from here we need some combinatorics to get the rest of answer.

Comment: Notice the equation in the title is not the same as the one in the body of your Question.  Please fix this and add any observations you made about existence of solutions or useful identities.

Comment: Title differs from question.

Comment: $x^n + y^n = 2^{100}$ or $x^n - y^n = 2^{100}$? The body of your problem does not agree with your title.

Comment: opps ... fixing that .. :)

Comment: for $n>2$ you can invoke Fermat's last theorem and, at least remove from consideration many values of $n$

Comment: @DougM Not that many; just those that divide $100$.

Comment: I think this falls to the lifting the exponent lemma.

Comment: I didn't want to plagiarise, so [here](http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/p105s.html) is your answer! Hope it helps.

Comment: @Rohan Thanks :)

Comment: @RezwanArefin No problem.

Comment: @Rohan I didn't get this why they conclude $, (a, b) = (1, 99), (2, 98), ... , (49, 51)$. But why $(50,50)$ is not there? And how they got this :|

Comment: We have that if $(x-y)=(x+y)=2^{50} $, then we will get $x=2^{50} $ and $y=0$. But both should be positive integers which is not satisfied by $y $. Hence, $(50,50) $ is not permitted.

Comment: @Rohan I don't understand why that is plagiarism. Plagiarism, according to the Oxford Dictionary, is defined as " The practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own." If you cite the source, it is hardly plagiarism. Of course, I think that the words were not your own, you should make it a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is being asked rather often and the solution in the comments seems to have a flaw I propose the following answer.

---

We claim: the equation
$$
a^n-b^n=2^k,\tag1
$$
where $a,b,n,k$ are positive integers ($n>1$), has exactly $\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}2\right\rfloor$ solutions $(a,b)$ for $n=2$ and no solutions for $n>2$.

First of all we note that from
$$
a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-i}b^i=2^k,\tag2
$$
it immediately follows that the solution can exist for $n>1$ only if $k>0$.

Now let consider the problem case by case.

For $n=2$ from
$$
a-b=2^r,\quad a+b=2^{k-r}
$$
the only solutions are:
$$a=2^{k-r-1}+2^{r-1};\quad b=2^{k-r-1}-2^{r-1},\quad 0<r<\frac{k}2.\tag3$$

For $n=4$ we would have the equation:
$$
(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)=2^k.
$$

This implies
$$a^2-b^2=2^m\implies a=2^{m-r-1}+2^{r-1};\quad b=2^{m-r-1}-2^{r-1}$$
for some $m$ and $r$.
But the equation
$$
2^{2(m-r-1)}+2^{2(r-1)}=\frac{a^2+b^2}2=2^{k-m-1}
$$
cannot hold in view of $r\ne\frac m2$ (cf. (3)).

For odd $n>1$ we note that equation (2) can hold only if both $a$ and $b$ are even: $a=2A$, $b=2B$. Assume now that equation (1) has an integer solution $(a,b)$ for some $k$. Then there must exist some minimal positive $K$ for which the equation holds. However from
$$
(2A)^n-(2B)^n=2^K\implies A^n-B^n=2^{K-n}
$$
it follows that such minimal $k$ does not exist (since $n<K$).

In general case an arbitrary $n>2$ can be represented as $2^p q$, where $q$ is an odd number. If $p>0$ repeating the process:
$$
2^k=a^n-b^n=(a^{n/2}-b^{n/2})(a^{n/2}+b^{n/2})\implies a^{n/2}-b^{n/2}=2^m;\ (
m>0)$$
one reduces the problem either to $n=4$ (if $q=1$) or $n$ odd (if $q\ne1$). The obtained contradiction finalizes the proof.